# Chart is not displaying (google charts + codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-visualization

I'm trying to display a simple chart but it's not showing on localhost. I'm using codeigniter framework+google charts.

I want to display this simple chart: [Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Speb.jpg)

`Data_model.php`:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Data_model extends CI_Model {

private $performance = 'sportoviska_zakaznici';

function __construct() {

}

function get_chart_data() {


   return $this->db->query('SELECT pohlavie, count(*) as counts FROM sportoviska_zakaznici GROUP BY rok')->result_array();
}

}
```

`Charts.php` (controller):

```
class Charts extends CI_Controller {


function __Construct() {
    parent::__Construct();

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
       $this->load->model('data_model', 'chart');

}

public function index()
{

            $data['chart_data'] = $this->chart->get_chart_data();

    $this->load->view('uvodna_stranka', $data);
}


}
```

`uvodna_stranka.php` (view):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">



            // Load the Visualization API and the line package.
           // google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar', 'timeline']});
             google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {

              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['pohlavie', 'counts'}],
<?php
foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
    echo "['".$data["pohlavie"]."', ".$data["counts"]."],";
}
?>  
               var options = {

                        title: 'Company Performance'

                };

     var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

            }

       </script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <b>Bla bla<b>
            <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to display data from this MySQL table:
[Mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfzU8.png)

When I try to access it from my localhost chart is not being displayed. This is how it looks: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz9tx.png)

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the browser's console for errors (press F12 on most)

there are a couple issues here...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['pohlavie', 'counts'}],

<?php
foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
    echo "['".$data["pohlavie"]."', ".$data["counts"]."],";
}
?>
```

first, there is a ending curly brace out of place after --> `'counts'}`
remove it...

next, the array for the data doesn't have ending braces --> `]);`

change above to...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['pohlavie', 'counts'],

      <?php
      foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
          echo "['".$data["pohlavie"]."', ".$data["counts"]."],";
      }
      ?>  
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have syntax problems, you have a closing bracket in *['pohlavie', 'counts'**}**],* which doesn't even open or has any porpouse I think.

Then when you have the data, in which you never close the tags from the function:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['pohlavie', 'counts'}],
<?php
foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
 echo "['".$data["pohlavie"]."', ".$data["counts"]."],";
}
```

I went on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts and found out you should probably be using the following first example. In your case it should go along the lines of the following instead of your **var data**:

```
data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'pohlavie');
data.addColumn('number', 'counts');
data.addRows([
<?php 
    foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
        echo '["'.$data["pohlavie"].'","'.$data["counts"].'"]';
    }
?>
]);
```

Just to be sure you should check the examples of the google charts documentation.